# Laravel Pivot Table belongsToMany

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, eloquent

I'm new on php and Laravel, so I have a lot of doubts.
I'm using phpmyadmin and have the next relationship:

```
Table:| productos | tipos  | marcas | producto_tipo_marca (pivot table)
      | id        |  id    | id     | id
      | id_tipo   | nombre | nombre | id_producto
      | id_marca  |        |        | id_tipo
      |           |        |        | id_marca
```

(I work names in english)
So, the table product(productos) have a realtionship with the foreing_keys id_type(id_tipo) and id_brand(id_marca). A product have Many-Many relationship with type and brand.

Question 1: Did a need a Pivot Table or not? (Sorry but I'm alone in my job and have the doubt)

I have been working with jquery and listing data (all fine) but on the product.index I whant to show the id_type->nambe and the id_brand->nambe, but all I can show on the datatable it's the id_type and id_brand (showing only numeric data):

View: product.index

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    <td>{{ $product->id_type}}</td>
    <td>{{ $product->id_brand }}</td>
@endforeach
```

When I do something like:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    <td>{{ $product->id_type->name}}</td>
    <td>{{ $product->id_brand->name}}</td>
@endforeach
```

Have the error: Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\posm\app\views\productos\index.blade.php)

So, I watch a lot of tutorials but can't get the core.

In my models have this:

Product (Model)

```
protected $guarded = array();
protected $table = 'products';
protected $fillable = array('id_type','id_brand');
```

Question 2: Did I need to specify somethin like: id_type->name or I can't do somethin like that?

Type (Model)

```
protected $guarded = array();
protected $table = 'type';
protected $fillable = array('name');

public function products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Product'); //Access the model Product.
}
```

Brand (Model)

```
protected $guarded = array();
protected $table = 'brand';
protected $fillable = array('name');

public function products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Product'); //Access the model Product.
}
```

ProductController

```
public function index()
{
    $products = $this->product->all();
    return View::make('product.index', compact('product'));
}
```

Question 3: Did I need to add some code here to specify than product get the id_type->name and id_brand->name or just let it like I have it?

Questions: 
What I need to do? 
¿Just for get the id_type->name and the id_brand->name on my jquery datatable? 
¿I need a pivot table and do some code on models and controllers? Or can get the type and brand name directly on the view product.blade?

Sorry for the long question. I'll be grateful for any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not and advanced mysql user, but I think you don't need the pivot table.
You need the tables: productos, tipos and marcas.

If you are accessing the data from the "Product" model, you need to add this relation in Product.php:
(I didn't understand if you are using english or spanish for your code).

```
public function type()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Type', 'type_id');
}

public function brand()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Brand', 'brand_id');
}
```

If you need to automatically load this relationships on every query, you need to add this property:

```
public $with = ['type', 'brand'];
```

If not, you can specify when making the query instead of adding the $with property, like this:

```
Product::with(['type', 'brand'])->get();
```

Then you can do:

```
$products = Product::with(['type', 'brand'])->get();
```

And in the view:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    {{ $product->type->name }}
    {{ $product->brand->name }}
@endforeach
```

I didn't test the code, so check it before using it!

The Laravel documentation is great, you should take a look at it: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent

Comment: Work's me at the first try, many thanks for your help and time!